# Nested alignment in equation

Tags: equations, alignment, alignat

I'd like to obtain the alignment shown in the figure. I've tried with `alignat` and did some research, but got weird results. There are 2 distinct alignments, the thick red line and the thin one. Ignore the arrows and text in grey. Thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: For the subsidiary aligned group, you can use `\begin{aligned}[t] ... \end{aligned}\\`.  There is probably another question that has an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @barbarabeeton has already noted in a comment, the way to go is to embed an `aligned` environment inside the `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
0
&= \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta X + \Delta Y + \Delta Z + \dotsb \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta X + R_{iy}
     \begin{aligned}[t]
       &\bigl[ \nabla_{\!j}\nabla_{\!k} + \dotsb \\
       &+\nabla_{\!i}\nabla_{\!k} + \dotsb \\
       &-\tfrac{1}{6}\nabla_{\!i}\nabla_{\!j}\bigr] -\tfrac{1}{12} \Delta R\Delta S 
     \end{aligned} \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta X + \Delta Y + \Delta Z + \dotsb \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta X + \Delta Y + \Delta Z + \dotsb \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}\Delta X + \Delta Y + \Delta Z + \dotsb \end{align*}

\end{document}
```